# Summing up cell values based on header row and column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables, excel-365

I have a table that is used to track costs and their status. The table below is a structured table with the name "COLOG"

[image: COLOG Table]

I am trying to consolidate values of the respective column values basing on their status as follows:
[image: Summary table]

In cell AE2, this is the code i attempted:

```
=INDEX(COLOG,MATCH(1,(AE1=COLOG[STATUS]),0),MATCH(AD2,COLOG[[#Headers],[Project Manager]:[MEP Engineer]],0))
```

which returned an #NA error.
Cell AD2 is a dynamic array. The intention is to have sum up everything in the COLOG table that matches the value in the AD2 dynamic array and also the AE:AI headers.

Comment: Please put the input data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) format, it helps to reproduce the scenario in Excel and your question gets more attraction.

Answer (score 1):

### Sum Up Based on Row and Column Labels

[image]

**Dynamic Array**

- I used the following dynamic array formula in cell `AD2`:

  ```
  =TOCOL(COLOG[[#Headers],[PM]:[ME]])
  ```

  so it could be referred to with `AD2#`.

**Hard-Coded**

```
=LET(sd,COLOG,drc,AD2#,dlr,AE1:AI1,
    sci,XMATCH(drc,COLOG[#Headers]),
    dci,XMATCH(COLOG[Status],dlr),
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(drc),COLUMNS(dlr),LAMBDA(r,c,
    SUM(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(sd,CHOOSEROWS(sci,r)),dci=c)))))
```

The major issue (shouldn't be one) with the following two formulas is that they will fail if someone changes the title of the *Status* column which won't happen using the previous formula.

**Flexible**

- Removed the redundant variables from the last formula.

```
=LET(sTable,COLOG[#All],slcTitle,"Status",drc,AD2#,dlr,AE1:AI1,
    sh,TAKE(sTable,1),
    sci,XMATCH(drc,sh),
    sd,DROP(sTable,1),
    dci,XMATCH(CHOOSECOLS(sd,XMATCH(slcTitle,sh)),dlr),
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(drc),COLUMNS(dlr),LAMBDA(r,c,
    SUM(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(sd,CHOOSEROWS(sci,r)),dci=c)))))
```

**Maintainable**

- This is how I build the previous formulas.
- Note that you can replace the last `dr` with any variable above the first `dr`.
- Similarly, you can replace the last `dSum` with any variable above the first `dSum`. To see the result of arrays, you'll have to replace the last `dSum` with e.g. `TEXTJOIN(", ",,dSum)` before replacing `dSum`.

```
=LET(sTable,COLOG[#All],slcTitle,"Status",drc,AD2#,dlr,AE1:AI1,
    sh,TAKE(sTable,1),
    sci,XMATCH(drc,sh),
    sd,DROP(sTable,1),
    slCol,XMATCH(slcTitle,sh),
    slc,CHOOSECOLS(sd,slCol),
    dci,XMATCH(slc,dlr),
    dr,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(drc),COLUMNS(dlr),LAMBDA(r,c,LET(
        srCol,CHOOSEROWS(sci,r),
        src,CHOOSECOLS(sd,srCol),
        dSum,SUM(FILTER(src,dci=c)),
    dSum))),
dr)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a combination of SUMIF and XLOOKUP in cell AE2 as follows:

```
=SUMIF(COLOG[Status],$AE$1:$AI$1,XLOOKUP(AD2,COLOG[[#Headers],[Project Manager]:[MEP Engineer]],COLOG[[Project Manager]:[MEP Engineer]]))
```

The table column returned by XLOOKUP, based on the value in AD2, is used as the *sum_range* in SUMIF, and since we've used range $AE$1:$AI$1 as the *criteria*, the results will spill across AE2:AI2.

This method alone will not spill down, however. If you attempt to use AD2# or AD2:AD4 as the *lookup_value* in XLOOKUP, it will return the #VALUE! error. You must copy/drag the formula in cell AE2 down manually for each applicable item in column AD.

Alternatively, to make the results spill both across and down, you can combine the above-mentioned formula with MAKEARRAY in cell AE2 as follows:

```
=LET(
_items, AD2:AD4,
_status, AE1:AI1,
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_items), COLUMNS(_status), LAMBDA(r,c,
   SUMIF(COLOG[Status], INDEX(_status, c),
   XLOOKUP(INDEX(_items, r), COLOG[[#Headers],[Project Manager]:[MEP Engineer]], COLOG[[Project Manager]:[MEP Engineer]]))))
)
```

Adjust the range references accordingly to meet your needs. Cheers!